# infinite loop in movement function

Tags: c++, infinite-loop

I have this program that is supposed to simulate fish and sharks moving around on a grid of any given size, but I'm running into an infinite loop in my fish's move function.

the program isn't consistent on when the looping occurs because when I run it sometimes it gets stuck on turn 0, but it could also happen on turn 3; this is possible because of my randomness attached to it

here's my fish_class.cpp where the problem occurs, I've marked where the infinite loop happens. hope anyone could help.

```
#include "fish_class.h"
#include "world.h"
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

void FishT::SetFishBreed(int fishBreedRate)
{
    fishBreed = fishBreedRate;
    
    //return fishBreed;
}

int FishT::GetFishBreed()
{
    return fishBreed;
}

int FishT::IncreaseMoves()
{
    if (moveCount == fishBreed) //just incase for unlimited breeding
    {
        moveCount = 0;
    }
    
    moveCount++;
        
    return moveCount;
}

void FishT::Move(WorldT& world)
{    
    bool HasMoved = false;
    
    srand (time (NULL)); //initialize random seed
    
    //generate a number from 1 to 4 (north, south, east, west) to move to on the world grid
    int PlaceToMove = static_cast<int>(rand() % 4 + 1);
    
    while (HasMoved == false)
    {    
        if (PlaceToMove == 1 and world.IsInBoundry(x, y - 1) and world.IsEmpty(x, y - 1)) //checking if north is empty and in bounds
        {
            //cout << "moving fish north" << endl;
            //update fish's position
            world.SetEmpty(x, y);
            world.SetFishPlacement(x, y - 1);    
            y = y - 1;
                    
            HasMoved = true;
            Turn(world); //increase our move tracker
        }
        else if (PlaceToMove == 2 and world.IsInBoundry(x, y + 1) and world.IsEmpty(x, y + 1)) //checking if south is empty and in bounds
        {
            //cout << "moving fish south" << endl;
            //update fish's position
            world.SetEmpty(x, y);
            world.SetFishPlacement(x, y + 1);
            y = y + 1;
        
            HasMoved = true;
            Turn(world);
        }
        else if (PlaceToMove == 3 and world.IsInBoundry(x + 1, y) and world.IsEmpty(x + 1, y)) //checking if east is empty
        {
            //cout << "moving fish east" << endl;
            //update fish's position
            world.SetEmpty(x, y);
            world.SetFishPlacement(x + 1, y);
            x = x + 1;
        
            HasMoved = true;
            Turn(world);
        }
        else if (PlaceToMove == 4 and world.IsInBoundry(x - 1, y) and world.IsEmpty(x - 1, y)) //checking if west is empty
        {
            //cout << "moving fish west" << endl;
            //update fish's position
            world.SetEmpty(x, y);
            world.SetFishPlacement(x - 1, y);
            x = x - 1;
        
            HasMoved = true;
            Turn(world);
        }
        else
        {
        // *** this is where the loop problem occurs ***

            //cout << "updating fish's placetomove" << endl; 
            PlaceToMove = PlaceToMove % 4 + 1; 
        }
    }
    
    if (PlaceToMove == 1 and moveCount == fishBreed)
    {
        //cout << "in reproduce north" << endl;
        //cout << "fish breed is: " << GetFishBreed() << endl;
        //cout << "move count is: " << moveCount << endl;
        Reproduce(x, y + 1, world);
    }
    else if (PlaceToMove == 2 and moveCount == fishBreed)
    {
        //cout << "in reproduce south" << endl;
        //cout << "fish breed is: " << GetFishBreed() << endl;
        //cout << "move count is: " << moveCount << endl;
        Reproduce(x, y - 1, world);
    }
    else if (PlaceToMove == 3 and moveCount == fishBreed)
    {
        //cout << "in reproduce east" << endl;
        //cout << "fish breed is: " << GetFishBreed() << endl;
        //cout << "move count is: " << moveCount << endl;
        Reproduce(x - 1, y, world);
    }
    else if (PlaceToMove == 4 and moveCount == fishBreed)
    {
        //cout << "in reproduce west" << endl;
        //cout << "fish breed is: " << GetFishBreed() << endl;
        //cout << "move count is: " << moveCount << endl;
        Reproduce(x + 1, y, world);
    }
}

void FishT::Reproduce(int x, int y, WorldT& world)
{
    //cout << "in reproduce function" << endl;
    world.SetFishPlacement(x, y);
    world.AddNewFish(x, y); 
}

void FishT::Turn(WorldT& world)
{
    IncreaseMoves();  //keep track of move turns
}

void FishT::Die(WorldT& world)
{
    world.FishDie(x, y);    
}
```

Comment: Could it just be, that there is no available position?

Comment: Also you're mixing C code with C++.

Comment: Tangential: `rand()` isn't great randomness to begin with, but repeatedly calling `srand` will really degrade the quality of the random numbers you get.

Comment: This might be caused by `IsInBoundry` and/or `IsEmpty` returning an incorrect result.

Comment: Unrelated: Rather than four essentially identical chunks of code, you could have a static array to hold the {x, y} offsets for each of the four moves, then use a loop to check if the move in that direction is valid and handle the move.

Comment: Unrelated: `static_cast<int>(rand() % 4 + 1)` -- the cast isn't needed. `rand()` returns `int`, all the operations involve `int`s, so the type of the result is already `int`.

Comment: What are x and y, and how are they initialized? This will always be prone to infinite loops as soon as 4 squares are occupied by fish and 1 can't move. Consider changing the algorithm to let the fish Idle if all options are exhausted